# Apache 2.2.20 + PHP 5.2.6 installation

Tags: php, apache, configuration

I need to install PHP 5.2.6 on Apache 2.2.20 (UBUNTU 11.10) (local server).
I've already install Apache, now I want to install PHP but there is a problem :

I've downloaded php-5.2.6.tar.gz, `gunzip` it, `tar -xvf` it, then in the instructions, I've to run `./configure --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql`, but I don't have  dir named apxs.
So I've tried to run `./configure --with-mysql`, it's works.
Finally, I've to run `make` and `make install` in my php-5.2.6 folder, but I've an error :

`make: *** Pas de cibles spécifiées et aucun makefile n'a été trouvé. Arrêt.`

(In english : ~ there is no makefile. stop)

Please help !
I really need this version of PHP, is there something wrong in my steps ? Is there a better way to install PHP 5.2.6 on Apache 2.2.20 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't install it via apt? The version of PHP provided by ubuntus package repository is even newer.

Comment: Ubuntu installs on my computer PHP 5.3.

Comment: But as far as I know 5.3 > 5.2 :? Really: 5.3 is out for around 2.5 years old now. Also 5.4 is going to get released in the next month. You need _really_ good reasons, if you really _require_ 5.2 (and no: Strict-, or deprecated notices are not "good reasons").

Comment: Humm, I just need PHP 5.2.6 for an old project. Tried with the latest PHP version, but it's fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed apache2-threaded-dev the apxs are not part of the package, you need to uninstall it and install prefork to have apxs2 :

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2-threaded-dev
sudo apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
```

That should do the trick. Then just do your standard PHP compile. Not even sure you need to specify apxs2 folder to PHP.

If you get the "aucun makefile n'a été trouvé" error, that means your ./configure failed. If so, please copy the last lines of your ./configure here.

Comment: `Configuring extensions
checking whether to enable LIBXML support... yes
checking libxml2 install dir... no
checking for xml2-config path... 
configure: error: xml2-config not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.
` ... but I've libxml2 already installed

Comment: Make sure you have libxml2-dev installed, it seems to be your problem.